# Active user count

Tags: c++, locking, multiple-users

Trying to understand how a software is counting concurrent users connected.
Tried to analyze the machine on which is installed. (Registry and files modified) but nothing found. Best approach ?

Edit: Transferred to su and resolved.

Comment: This should be on SU not SO.  We help with programming here, not programs.

Comment: unless you want to hack it :) seriously, you could see if the software runs a `tasklist` command. In which case you could substitute a fake tasklist and feed it to your old program.

Comment: Totally agree with @NathanOliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferred to su and resolved with Wireshark